# DataTemplates and the MVVM framework

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

as I go on in trying to create a simple example, I came across a lot of issues when dealing with DataTemplates with the MVVM concept.

In order to get familiar with DataTemplates, the idea is as follows. Just create a DataTemplate with content (in this case a label that displays the name and the button that displays the age) that is bound to my view model.

Before the questions, here is the code.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
namespace tutorial
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private MainWindow mw;
        private ViewModel vm;

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            vm = new ViewModel();
            mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.DataContext = ?
            mw.Activate();
            mw.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
namespace tutorial
{
    class ViewModel
    {
        private String name;

        private int age;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            name = "Hello World";
        }

        public int Age
        {
            get {return age;}
            set {age = value;}
        }

        public String Name
        {
            get {return name;}
            set {name = value;}
        }
    }
}
```

**Button.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tutorial">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding ??}" />
            <Button Content="{Binding ???}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="tutorial.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
</Window>
```

So I have the following questions:

The following line of code `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">` displays that the name ViewModel does not exists in the namespace, clearly it does right? Or am I missing something? An image of the solution explorer is shown below:

[image: Directory tree in solution explorer]

The second question is more important and it also shows that I do now know how to bind the view to the viewmodel. The questionmarks in **App.xaml.cs**, **Button.xaml** and possibly some errors in **MainWindow.xaml** as I do not know how the MainWindow knows which content I want it to show.

Thank you for your help.

Here is a [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=46366874394927584934) to the entire project, as a response to the previous comments:

[image: Problem of namespaces]

Comment: set your ViewModel to public, and it should work

Comment: I'm sorry, it did not fix the first problem. It still doesn't seem to be able to find ViewModel.

Comment: Where is the resource dictionary resources located,
i suppose its app.xaml..Is it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set Viewmodel to be a public class, it does exist in the namespace but no other classes can see it.

```
namespace tutorial
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

Bindings needed for the data template

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Age}" />
        <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Setting DataContext

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            vm = new ViewModel();
            mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.DataContext = vm;
            mw.Show();
        }
```

Add resource dictionary

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Button.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

[Fixed full project available here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2qmBOqGJqZCdllfdGpNZlpIWnM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm sorry, but adding public to it does not seem to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean? Does it solve the exception? I will add some code to show you the other answers

Comment: It did not fix the first problem (please see the newly attached image).

Comment: Have you tried running the application? Sometimes xaml shows errors that don't really exist

Comment: After running the application with the code that you presented. There were no compile errors and it runs, but it doesn't work. I still do not see any buttons or labels.

Comment: Try moving the part where you set the data context to the MainWindow.xaml.cs inside the constructor. What it looks like you are doing is opening up a second main window with a set data context. Also add the resource dictionary to your apps resources if not already there.

Comment: I downloaded your project and added these fixes and it works. I moved setting the data context to the MainWindow.xaml.cs and removed the creation of the mainwindow from App.xaml.cs

Comment: Do you mind sharing your edited project? I am kind of clueless why the error still exists.

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the answer, there was an error in MainWindow.xaml where you hadn't closed a tag properly which caused the other error to appear for me, but it also wouldn't build like that.

Comment: Hmm, very strange. Your project indeed works! By the way one last question. Why do I need to add a resource dictionary to the App.xaml file? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: That adds it to the application wide resources, just creating a resource dictionary is not enough it needs to be included somewhere. This can be application wide or in local resources for a page/control/window etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also.

In the App.xaml.cs class

```
 public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel();
        var window = new MainWindow();
        window.DataContext = vm;
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

In App.xaml make sure you remove StartupUri namespace from App.xaml or two Mainwindow will appear.

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Button.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Rest the code for ViewModel.cs and Mainwindow.xaml remains the same...